# Is this the correct way to marshall an output byte array?

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling

I have the following function exported from a C dll:

```
// C
BOOL WINAPI GetAttributeValue(
        IN     TAG                      * psTag, 
        IN     DWORD                      dwEltIdx,
        IN     DWORD                      dwAttrIdx,
        OUT    BYTE                     * pbBuffer,
        IN OUT DWORD                    * pdwLen )

// C#
[DllImport(Simulator.ASSEMBLY, SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public extern static int GetAttributeValue(
        IntPtr tag_id,
        int element_index,
        int attribute_index,
        [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex=4)]
        byte[] data_buffer,
        [In, Out]
        ref int data_length
    );
```

This is how I'm trying to use it, based on several answers here on SO:

```
int result = -1;
byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
int length = buffer.Length;

result = Simulator.GetAttributeValue(
        tag.NativeId,
        element_index,
        attribute_index,
        buffer,
        ref length
    );

int[] output = new int[length];

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    output[i] = buffer[i];
}

return output;
```

Another thing I tried is this, also based on answers found on SO:

```
[DllImport(Simulator.ASSEMBLY, SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public extern static int GetAttributeValue(
        IntPtr tag_id,
        int element_index,
        int attribute_index,
        IntPtr data_buffer, // changed this
        [In, Out]
        ref int data_length
    );

// snip

GCHandle pinned_array = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
IntPtr pointer = pinned_array.AddrOfPinnedObject();

result = Simulator.GetAttributeValue(
        tag.NativeId,
        element_index,
        attribute_index,
        pointer,
        ref length
    );

// snip, copying stuff to output

pinned_array.Free();
return output;
```

Now, in both cases, my `length` seems to be filled in correctly, but `buffer` always remains empty. I'm not very well versed in P/Invoke and marshalling, so I'm not sure if any of this is correct. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If all else fails, consider writing a wrapper in c++/cli... If you do lots of calls like this it might even be easier to write and debug.

Comment: @jdv-JandeVaan: Luckily, I have only two API functions with buffers, otherwise it would be a major pain. I'm glad nobody found anything incorrect with the code so far.. >_>

Answer (score 1):

Both versions are fine, hard to guess what's wrong.  Quacks like a "simulator" that isn't simulating correctly.  An IntPtr for a tag id is odd.  You ought to do something reasonable with *result* like throw an exception when you get an error code.

A C function that requires you to pass a buffer is in general troublesome, you have to guess at the correct buffer size.  Picking 2048 is a hope-its-big-enough guess, that does go wrong when you guessed too low.  A common protocol for such a function is that you have to call it twice.  First with an intentionally low value for `data_length`, like 0.  Then the function returns an error code and sets `data_length` to the required buffer size.  You then call it again with the correctly sized buffer.  This is just a guess, it does fit your problem.

Comment: Hi there! "tag id" is just an opaque structure, it really is an IntPtr. I've removed all the error handling stuff for clarity, because I get no errors in either case. I may have to try and test the Simulator.ASSEMBLY with a C executable, just to make sure it's working correctly..maybe I'm just wasting my time for nothing! :\

Comment: That's certainly something you ought to verify, yes.  Intentionally setting some the array elements to a non-zero value and checking if they get set back to 0 would be a useful test as well.